# Why does a previous name I inputed repeat itself each time I input a new name on a form and click on add?

Tags: javascript, forms, for-loop, user-input, getelementbyid

JavaScript: My form input value keeps repeating itself. Each time I enter a new name in the input field and click on the add button, the previous name I entered repeats itself and the new name is also added to the name list. Hence, if I input two names, I end up getting three with the first one repeating itself before the new one. Find attached my code:

```js
let inputvalue = document.querySelector("#womansname");
let addbtn = document.querySelector("#submit");
let displayname = document.querySelector(".taskList");

let nameList=[]
let list= ""
let li=document.createElement("li");

addbtn.addEventListener("click", (e)=> {
      e.preventDefault();
     nameList.push( inputvalue.value)
     for (let index = 0; index < nameList.length; index++) {
      list += `<li>${nameList[index]}</li>`
}

      displayname.innerHTML=list;
      inputvalue.value=""

})
```

Comment: Try to create a small reproducible example [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that will help to understand your problem and get an idea of where your code needs correction.

Comment: I just did that @Nils Kähler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is that you don't reset your `list` every time you press your button. so you keep adding the previous data to the list. The simple solution is to move the list instantiation into the `click`-`eventListener`, then your list will only add the new data.

```js
let inputvalue = document.querySelector("#womansname");
let addbtn = document.querySelector("#submit");
let displayname = document.querySelector(".taskList");

let nameList = []
let li = document.createElement("li");

addbtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  nameList.push(inputvalue.value);
  let list = "";
  for (let index = 0; index < nameList.length; index++) {
    list += `<li>${nameList[index]}</li>`
  }

  displayname.innerHTML = list;
  inputvalue.value = "";
})
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="womansname" />
  <button id="submit">
  submit
  </button>
  <ul class="taskList">

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried adding the  alert function for so a user can get an error mgs alert when the input field is empty and the add button get clicked but it I keep getting an error message.